# Getting 403 forbidden when signing in with google to WSO2 API Manager Devportal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, google-authentication, wso2-appm, wso2-identity-server

I am getting the `403` forbidden error when I am signing in with google to the WSO2 API store.

I get this error message:

> You don't have sufficient privileges to access the Developer Portal

Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2):

In order to login to the developer portal, the user must have the Internal/subscriber role. Please check the user that you are trying to login has this role assigned.